# Orchard Module not using updated nuget package

Tags: orchardcms

I am encountering an issue when I upload my module's nuget package to a production environment.  When I package my module up into a nuget package and then open it locally, in NuGet package explorer, it has "Mcrf.ProfilesWeb.Contracts, Version=1.0.1.1" inside.

When I install my module package on the Orchard CMS, my page fails and when checking the error log, I see:

"System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Mcrf.ProfilesWeb.Contracts.ProfileList' from assembly 'Mcrf.ProfilesWeb.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

I've ensured numerous times that the module package is 100% correct, it seems as though the production environment Orchard site doesn't update the contract when installing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Roka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was hosting my website using Azure Web App, the resolution was to restart the Web App.  It seems Orchard somehow caches DLLs and that's why it continued to use an old version; restarting forced to look for the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a different version of ..ProfileList in your production environment than you do in your development environment

Comment: ProfileList is a return type of one of my methods and is defined in contract version 1.0.1.1 and if production still uses 1.0.0.4 even though my module package has 1.0.1.1, it makes sense that it doesn't know about this return type.  Is there someplace inside the Orchard database that version 1.0.0.4 is located and I can delete it?

Comment: Ah sorry, misread. Where is your production environment? Are there any error logs during the package upload? As you say, it doesn't sound like it is updating correctly...

Comment: There is nothing in my error log that indicates an unsuccessful upload of my module's nuget package. I'm certain Orchard is holding on to the old version of my contract.  For testing purposes,  I changed the return type to not be ProfileList, and the next error recorded is not recognizing a new method I put into the contract.  All indications lead to having an outdated contract and not updating when it's suppose to (with the module update).

Comment: Where is your production environment? Do other packages work?

Comment: The production environment is on Azure and yes other packages are still up and running.  It's worth noting that I also have a staging environment which runs on Azure and should have all the other modules and preferences similar to production and the module in question has worked wonderfully for weeks on there.

Comment: The staging environment was also hosted on Azure

Comment: Both are hosted using Web App

Comment: Inside of .net, I use powercommands to create the module nuget package then to install for the first time, or any subsequent updates, I go to modules -> install from computer in the admin tools for the website.  This is the only way i've ever done it.